# QuickLook and plist files

Tags: quicklook, plist

I have the latest Xcode installed, but I can't "quicklook" plist files (I mean they appear as an xml file instead of a table). Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik yes. This is normal.
You can drag n drop the plist onto Xcode and it should open it in a tree form

Answer (score 0):

Plist files and .properties-files can't normally be QuickLook'ed. You could try to [QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.com/qlstephen/), which let's you QuickLook any files without an extension, and with extensions such as .plist and .properties (according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/298920/136933)) in plain text.

Comment: Finder seems to be able to QuickLook binary .plists (However I do have Xcode installed)

Comment: QLStephen works great but you need to configure it to handle files with extensions like this: https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/issues/23